# Hibernate NHibernate - Native SQL

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hibernate

Trying to delete an unmapped class/record via the NHibernate sql api.
But can't seem to get it working. Does anything look wrong with this?

```
session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();

        tx = session.BeginTransaction();
        using (tx)
        {
            session.CreateSQLQuery("DELETE FROM tb_category WHERE parentID = :parentID").SetInt64("parentID",pID);

            tx.Commit();
        }
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you have to execute the Query to make it do something.

You're just creating a Query and setting it's parameters.

In Hibernate there is an .executeUpdate() method for the SQLQuery object that runs the native query.