# Force query execution without flush/commit

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, transactions

Hi i am using the transaction-per-request (session-in-view) pattern for an asp.net web application. I have a couple of points in the application where i want to Save an NHibernate managed entity and then do a couple of more inserts and updates using common sql. These inserts/updates depend on the ID that the NH saved entity will take.

The problem is that the generated id does not exist in the transactions' scope. If i force a flush/commit the id is persisted but if the inserts/updates fail i have to rollback but the flushed/committed entity will not. Currently I'm doing a manual insert for these cases but that is something i want to change. So,  is there a way to execute the SQL statement (inside the already open transaction) after the Save() but without forcing a flush/commit?

EDIT: I'm adding a semi-pseudocode example, i got 4 wrong answers so i think people don't understand (how NHibernate works)
At the Begin request i issue a

```
nhsession.BeginTransaction()
```

then at some point i do

```
FooClass fc = new FooClass("value");
nhsession.Save(fc);
ITransaction trans = nhsession.Transaction;
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("some insert/update query that depends on fc's id", (SqlConnection)nhsession.Connection);
sc.Parameters.Add("id", fc.Id); //NHibernate generates the id, note i'm using assigned/hi-lo so no round trip to the db takes place
transaction.Enlist(sc);
try {
    sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException ex){
    transaction.RollBack();
    nhsession.Close();
}
```

and at the end of the Request i issue a `CommitTransaction()` and `nhsession.Close()`

Now this will do absolutely nothing: the `FooClass (fc)` has not been flushed/commited to the database. The `Save()` operation that NH has done is up to that point in-memory. That means no sql command has been issued by nhibernate and that means that the `SqlCommand (sc)` that i fire afterwards will fail miserably as the id does not exist.

If i do a flush/commit between `Save()` and the `SqlCommand` the `FooClass(fc)` _cannot_be_rolled_back_ and that is a bad bad thing.
Currently, for this to work i make vanila sql insert using an `SqlCommand`, and i want to change that. (Why? because i don't want to make vanilla inserts they are susceptible to errors due to schema/model changes, and i got the OR/M for that)

How? i want to notify NHibernate somehow to execute the `SqlCommand` to corresponds to the `Save()` insert (hell, it can do all the SqlCommands it has gathered) but without it commiting or flushing!.

Currently i'm also searching for the prepared sql statement that nhibernate produces when flushing/commiting a saved object. Maybe i can just take that string and run it in my SqlCommand that is enlisted in the Transaction.

Comment: @Jaguar: I guess there's a gap in my understanding of the situation. I guess the Save() method provides you with the Id generated by NHibernate whatever it is hi/lo or identity or else. Can't you just use this returned value? I don't remember by heart, but I think it is the persisted object that is returned. Then, calling the Save() will provide with the Id value you need, then use this value within your other SQL statement (sc). Otherwise, wouldn't it be better to use the ISession.CreateSQLQuery() method instead of this SqlCommand? This method lets you run SQL statement against the DB directl

Comment: Wouldn't it help to include your Save() statement within a your transaction? So when the Id is returned by Save(), you could just use it into the other SQL DML statement? Then Flush() everything from the session, so if your Insert (Save()) fails, this would automatically be rollbacked by your transaction's Rollback() method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe I don't understand but can't you do it like so...

```
using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.Save(entity);
    session.Flush();

    //perform non NH operations with entity.id

    tx.Commit();
}//uncommitted transaction would be rolled back on dispose()
```

Comment: I still think the Flush will do what you want here. To explicitly flush the insert statement to db instead of waiting for commit to call flush.

Comment: you cannot rollback flushed objects

Comment: The insert would be rolled back. What does it mean to rollback flushed object?

Comment: in your example, if the non-NH operations fail for some reason, the tx.Rollback() call will not remove the entity you saved because you flushed it. And (to say this) at least this is the behaviour with NH2.0 and onwards that i have tried: Once you flush/commit you cannot revert the changes

Comment: I don't know what to tell you except that the session.Flush does not commit the transaction and the insert would indeed be rolled back.

Comment: have you tried using transactionscope instead of nhibernate transaction?

Comment: it seems that an error existed in my code that would force a commit, so i'm accepting this as the correct although technically the question is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use nested transactions or transaction scopes to support this?

Essentially what you are asking is for nh to assign the id before you use it,  generated ids are only assigned when changes are flushed, changes are flushed only at transaction boundaries therefore can you not create an inner transaction scope to wrap the nh related persistence forcing the flush and id generation but still allowing the outer transaction to fail and roll back all work if one of the stored procedures fail.

[How do I do nested transactions in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192111/how-do-i-do-nested-transactions-in-nhibernate) has some sample code that demos an approach using scopes.

Comment: Very interesting, on first look it seems to fit the bill and i'm giving it a +1 until i can test it to see if it actually works

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want ´dirty read´ isolation level during your transaction. This will allow you to read ´uncommited´ but ´saved´ content. I´m however not fluent enough in NHibernate to give any insight on how to do it there.

I´m sure someone else can hook in on how to do ´dirty read´ isolation level for NH.

Comment: actually no. Any operation done within a transaction is visible within that transaction. My isolation level is at ReadCommited (and it will stay like that). Besides that, read the question: NH's Save() does not execute the insert until NH's session is flushed/committed, so even if i had dirty reads, i would still get no results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Castle ActiveRecord on top of NHibernate but the princple should be the same, my DTC is disabled so I'm not positive this works, but this should be the correct direction.

```
Imports Castle.ActiveRecord
imports NHibernate.Expression

<ActiveRecord> _
Public Class Test1
    Inherits ActiveRecordBase(Of Test1)

    Private _id As Guid
    <PrimaryKeyAttribute(PrimaryKeyType.Guid)> _
    Public overridable Property Id as Guid
        Get
            return _id
        End Get

        Set(value As guid)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _prop1 As String
    <[Property]> _
    Public overridable Property prop1 as String
        Get
            return _prop1
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            _prop1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

<ActiveRecord> _
Public Class Test2
    Inherits ActiveRecordBase(Of Test2)

    Private _id As Guid
    <PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Guid)> _
    Public overridable Property Id as Guid
        Get
            return _id
        End Get

        Set(value As guid)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _prop1 As String
    <[Property]> _
    Public overridable Property prop1 as String
        Get
            return _prop1
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            _prop1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _t1 As Test1
    <BelongsTo()> _
    Public overridable Property t1 as Test1
        Get
            return _t1
        End Get

        Set(value As test1)
            _t1 = value
        End Set
    End Property


End Class
```

---

```
Imports Castle.ActiveRecord
Imports NHibernate.Expression
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Transactions
imports System.Configuration

Public Module Module1
    Public Class modMain
        Public Shared Sub Main()
            Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize()
            Using T As New System.Transactions.TransactionScope(ondispose.Rollback)
            Dim x As New Test1()
            x.prop1 = "Hello"
            x.Save

            using c As New SqlConnection()
                c.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Development").ConnectionString
                Dim cmd As SqlCommand = c.CreateCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into test2(prop1, t1) values(@prop1, @t1)"
                Dim p As SqlParameter = cmd.CreateParameter()
                p.Direction = parameterdirection.Input
                p.DbType = dbtype.Guid
                p.ParameterName = "@prop1"
                p.Value = "Test"

                cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
                p = cmd.CreateParameter()
                p.Direction = parameterdirection.Input
                p.DbType = dbtype.Guid
                p.ParameterName = "@t1"
                p.Value = x.Id

                c.Open
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            end using

            t.Complete
            end using

        End Sub
    End Class
End Module
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the NHibernate transaction, but from the way I understand it what you are doing should work correctly.  You can do effectively the same thing in a simple query window and it will work, I'm not sure exactly what is going on to make yours fail.  I'll get your sample up and running to duplicate the problem and see what I can find.  Have you tried using System.Transactions.Transactionscope instead of NHibernate transaction?

Comment: again, the ISession.Save() method does not make any inserts (it just places an order for the engine to do a Save on the passed object). It will only do so when we call ISession.Flush(). However, flushed objects cannot be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using NHibernate's direct SQL features? Instead of breaking out into SQLCommand which NHibernate knows nothing about you can use ISession.CreateSQLQuery("native SQL here"). If you then do this inside a transaction after your Save method NHibernate should execute all the statements in order when the Commit happens. Thus:

```
using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        FooClass fc = new FooClass("value");
        nhsession.Save(fc);

        var nativeQuery = nhsession.CreateSQLQuery("some insert/update query that depends on fc's id");

        // Add parameters to nativeQuery using SetXXX methods
        nativeQuery.SetXXX(...);

        // Save nativeQuery
        nativeQuery.Save(); // I think...

        tx.Commit();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        tx.Rollback();
    }
}
```

See this for another similar question regarding using the NH native query:  [Hibernate NHibernate - Native SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886017/hibernate-nhibernate-native-sql)